# how to capture javascript var value into asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have an asp.net page on which at a click on Button *(btn1)*, i want to show message box asking user a question **"Do you want to overwrite ?"** with button **"Ok/Overwrite"** and **"Cancel"** , and based on user response , i will have to update my database.

So i was trying to accomplish it using Javascript Confirm function

```
var r = Confirm('Do you want to overwrite ?)
```

but now i have to capture this `Var r` into my page so that i can update my database accordingly
any help how can i do it ?

Comment: y do u want 2 search for new code instead we have ajax confirmation control in ajaxtoolkit ... add that to button and no changes to be required in code ...

Comment: This Project doesn't have ajax tool kit.

Answer (score 1):

On this scenario, you don't need to pass in the value of `r` to the server; you simply don't postback.

Just have something like this:

```
<asp:button id="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Overwrite?');" OnClick="btn1_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

If the users clicks "OK" then the page will post back and you will update the DB. If the user clicks cancel, the page won't postback at all and you won't have to do anything.

Comment: My detail requirement is , A store can have only One Pword assigned to it , now i have store as drop down and P word as dropdown ,when user selects a store and P word and clicks Submit then this button first looks into database if that store already has another P word then it asks user that "another P word exists for this store , do you  want to overwrite that P word ?" , now if user selects Overwrite it simply updates P word and displays in table otherwise it displays previously existing Pword .

Comment: @Swapnilagrawal I see the whole flow now but the answer is almost the same: when you come back to the page asking the user for confirmation after checking that there's an existing record, you simply submit the form if the user clicks "OK"; otherwise, you don't submit the form since you are supposed to show the same page w/o change of any kind. I could show you how to do it if you post your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:- 
Add a hidden field in Net(.aspx) page

```
    <form id="form10" runat="server">

    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value="false" />
    </form>
```

The hidden field should be added under Form Tag.The value of this hidden field is initially "false".

Here is what you need to do in Code Behind file (.cs file)

```
    protected void btnSubmits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     if (hdnField.Value == "false")
            {

                AddJavascriptCode(itemValue); 
            }


        else if (hdnField.Value == "true")
        {

            lblMsg.Text = string.Format("You have entered {0}", itemValue);
            hdnField.Value = "false";
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to capture the response from OK/Confirm or Cancel button.

```
    private void AddJavascriptCode(string itemValue)
    {
        string script = @"<script language=""JavaScript"" type=""text/javascript"">
   window.onload=function()
  {
   var IsConfirm = 1;
   objField = document.getElementById('" + hdnField.ClientID + @"');
   objSubmit = document.getElementById('" + btnSubmit.ClientID + @"');
   IsConfirm = newConfirm('Test','You have entered " + itemValue + @" value. Do you want to overwrite ?',1,1,0);
   if(IsConfirm == true)
  {
  objField.value = 'true';
  objSubmit.click();
  }
  else
 {
  objField.value = 'false';
 }
}
function newConfirm(title,mess,icon,defbut,mods)
{
if (document.all)
{
retVal = confirm(mess);
retVal = (retVal==1)
}
else
{
retVal = confirm(mess);
}
return retVal;
}
</script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Test", script);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you :).